# tokenId generated from left shift operator vs. increment

Tags: erc-721, erc-1155, operator

```
tokenId = (nonce << 128); // i.e. 340282366920938463463374607431768211457, 680564733841876926926749214863536422913

vs.

tokenId = counter.increment(); // i.e. 1, 2, 3 incrementally
```

i see some projects use left shift operator to generate tokenId for 721 or 1155.

what would be the benefit over standard incremental approach?

Answer (score 0):

A benefit of using bitwise shift approach is that sometimes they are more gas efficient than the standard incremental approach (using arithmetic operators).

Comment: why is it gas efficient?